# How to make builds to prefer agents from private pool on TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I've got my private agent pool and there is also default pool on my TC server. My builds can run on both set of agents (no specific requirements for agents).

What I'd like to achieve is my builds to prefer private pool agents over default pool agents. Now, agent to run build on is choose by CPU rank I guess. So in case where all agents are free I'd like my builds to go to private pool agents. If no agents from private pool is free, I'd like my build to run on default pool agents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to configure agent priorities with help of the [plugin](https://github.com/grundic/teamcity-agent-priority).
Please enjoy ;)

Here is [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437761/how-to-set-build-agent-priority-in-teamcity) question.